# Python generator on dictionary view does not seem to be lazily evaluated

Tags: generator-expression

It's my understanding that python generator expressions return lazily evaluated comprehensions, and view objects on dictionaries update when their underlying dictionary is changed.

Given the following code (Python 2.7.6 Windows):

```
d = {}
gt_three = (x for x in d.viewkeys() if x > 3)
print list(gt_three)
d[1] = 'one'
d[4] = 'four'
print list(gt_three)
```

I would expect output like:

```
[]
[4]
```

Instead, I'm receiving:

```
[]
[]
```

If I recreate the generator after adding to the dictionary, or print the view itself, I do see the expected output.
What am I not understanding about generators? I'm quite new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generator expression returns an iterator, which you can only iterate over once. Attempts to iterate over an iterator after the first time will always see it as empty.

Comment: I see the difference now thank you, is the way to achieve what I'm looking for a generator function instead of an expression/comprehension?

Comment: @Dragos: It depends. I'd probably use `[x for x in d if x > 3]` and create a new list whenever you need one reflecting the new state, but that's a guess. You could define a class with an `__iter__` method implemented as a generator function, in which case every iteration over the object would get a new iterator.